# Uploading an image to Firestore. How to read file format before upload

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm using the expo-image-picker to select an image and then upload it to FireStore

```
const pickImage=async()=>{
  let result=await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes:ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    allowsEditing:true,
    aspect:[4,3],
    quality:1,
    
  });
  if (!result.cancelled){
    setSelectedImage(result.uri)
  }
}

let Enter = async () => {
  const storage=getStorage();
  const reference=ref(storage,title+'.png')

  const img=await fetch(selectedImage);
  const bytes=await img.blob();

  await uploadBytes(reference,bytes);

  await createEntry(title,descr);
};
```

The 'pickImage' function lets me pick the image from the computer, the 'Enter' function uploads it, then 'CreateEntry' just creates a seperate document which references the stored image.

Everything works fine except when I declare the reference constant under 'Enter'. If I don't include "+'.png'" after title it just shows up as a text document in Firestore. "+'.png'" is a workaround but obviously this limits me to just uploading pngs. I would like to create a 'documentFormat' variable which I could just add in there so it would look like:
`const reference=ref(storage,title+documentFormat)` but I can't figure out how to read the format of the selected document.

Answer (score 0):

The `ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync` method does not return a `mime type` for the selected file. What you can do is use this helper function to get the file extension and accordingly use it in place.

```js
function get_extension(url: string) {
    let extension = url.toLowerCase().split(".").pop();

    return extension; // png, mp4, jpeg etc.
}
```

### Usage

```js
const reference = ref(storage, title + get_extension(selectedImage))
```